# Spring localization with CookieLocaleResolver does not work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, localization

I have used spring localization as given [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-internationalization-i18n-localization-tutorial-example/).

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Registering ContextLoaderListener -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Registering DispatcherServlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**root-context.xml**

```
<!-- Loading Message Resource Bundle -->
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    <property name="cookieName" value="stcLocaleCookie" />
    <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="3600" />
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

and the spring-servlet.xml is having hibernate configuration beans propertyConfigurer, dataSource, sessionFactory, transactionManager.

Now when I load the page it is picking the localized text en, but when I try changing the url with ?lang=ar it is not working. However if I explicitly set the Accept-Language header as 'ar' it works, I have tried this using postman. How can I make it work to change the locale with url.

Answer (score 1):

can you try changing your root.xml with this

```
<!-- Loading Message Resource Bundle -->
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    <property name="cookieName" value="stcLocaleCookie" />
    <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="3600" />
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

and let me know if this helped

You can have a look at the spring documentation about Configuring Interceptors.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors

You can configure HandlerInterceptors or WebRequestInterceptors to be applied to all incoming requests or restricted to specific URL path patterns.

An example of registering interceptors in Java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new LocaleInterceptor());
    registry.addInterceptor(new ThemeInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns("/admin/**");
    registry.addInterceptor(new SecurityInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/secure/*");
 }

}
```

And in XML use the  element:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mapping path="/**"/>
        <exclude-mapping path="/admin/**"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mapping path="/secure/*"/>
        <bean class="org.example.SecurityInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried changes you suggested, it didn't work either.